# TeXShop is not compiling

Tags: texshop

I installed  MAC OS X 10.6.8 some weeks ago. Whenever I compile `.tex`  file the following message turns up:

> "Can't find required tool.
>    usr/textbin/pdflatex/simpdftex does not exist. Perhaps TeXLive was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to the TeXShop web site and follow the instructions to (re)install TeXLive. Another possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the fink teTeX distribution."

All I could has been done. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: As the error says, did you install TeX Live (MacTeX)?

Comment: shouldn't `usr/textbin/...` be `/usr/texbin/...`?

Comment: You state that you "installed MAC OS X 10.6.8 some weeks ago". Did you mean to say that you installed *MacTeX* on a Mac that's (still) running MacOSX 10.6.8? MacOS10.6 hasn't been sold by Apple in almost 2 years... Please also provide some information on what exactly you do when you "compile [a] .tex file".

Comment: This can sometimes be caused by a damaged preference file.  Quit TeXShop and move the file `~/Library/Preferences/TeXShop.plist` to the Desktop and then restart TeXShop.  If that fixes the problem you can delete the moved `.plist` file and you'll need to reset any preferences you had previously set.